# Laravel check if var is does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have condition:

```
{{ setting('notifications.email.enabled') ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

In `setting('notifications.email.enabled')` can be values: `1`, `0` and values can does not exist. How I can check if `setting('notifications.email.enabled')` does not exist (in table), and if does not exist, then `'checked'`. Now I get `''` on does not exist.

Comment: You want it to be empty only when it is 0?

Comment: Is `setting` a custom function? What does the function look like? Can't you look at something like [`config`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-config) and how that works?

Comment: "Now I get '' on does not exist." then what's wrong with `=== ''`?

Comment: @HtmHell I'm trying to understand the question. AFAIK if the return of `setting` is false / does no exist then surely the echo would just be `""`?

Comment: @KamalPaliwal yea

Comment: @JustCarty I use this package: https://github.com/anlutro/laravel-settings

Comment: Then you can compare it with 0 only and if its 0 then return '' else return 'checked'

Comment: `setting('notifications.email.enabled') !== 0 ? 'checked' : ''`

Comment: @KamalPaliwal is not working.. I get ''.

Comment: @MafysGrif check answer. That should work

Comment: @JustCarty when is zero I get `checked` but Need get ''.

Comment: @JustCarty again: I neet if record does not exist, I need get: checked, If record exists and equal `0` I need get '', If equal exists and equal true (1) I need get checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
{{ setting('notifications.email.enabled', true) ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

by setting a default value in the second parameter

Answer (score 0):

Compare it with 0 and return `checked` in else case such that if it is not set or it is 1 then it will return checked.

```
{{ (setting('notifications.email.enabled') === 0) ? '' : 'checked' }}
```

Comment: Sorry. Not Working :((

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Now: if record is does not exist I get '' but need get checked. If record exists and record == 0 I get correctly ''.

Comment: try var_dump(setting('notifications.email.enabled')). What it gives?

Comment: When does not exist: `null`.

Comment: In case of null it is returning '' ? Are you using === to compare?